# how to create semi donut chart in E-Chart

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, echarts

I want to make a "Half Doughnut" chart. It should be like first chart in the picture.

But in my chart space occupies above the chart (Second chart). is it possible to remove that space.

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPOUU.png

**My code :**

```
option = {

    legend: {
        orient: 'vertical',
        x: 'left',
        data: ['直接访问', '邮件营销', '联盟广告', '视频广告', '搜索引擎']
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'half semi',
            type: 'pie',
            radius: ['50%', '70%'],
            center: ['50%', '100%'],
            startAngle: 180,
            endAngle: 360,
            avoidLabelOverlap: false,
            label: {
                normal: {
                    show: false,
                    position: 'center'
                },

            },
            labelLine: {
                normal: {
                    show: false
                }
            },
            data: [
                { value: 3, name: 'ok' },
                { value: 5, name: 'bad' },
                { value: 2, name: 'warning' },
                { value: 10, name: 'bottom' }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
option = {
tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    formatter: function (p) {
        console.log(p)
            return `${p.name}: ${p.value} ${p.percent*2}%`;
        }
},
legend: {
    orient: 'vertical',
    left: 10,
},
series: [
    {  
        startAngle: 180,
        endAngle: 360, 
        type: 'pie',
        radius: ['50%', '70%'],
        avoidLabelOverlap: false,
        label: {
            show: false,
            position: 'center'
        },
        emphasis: {
            label: {
                show: true,
                fontSize: '30',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        labelLine: {
            show: false
        },
        data: [
            {value: 1, name: 'data-a'},
            {value: 1, name: 'data-b'},
            {value: 3, name: 'data-c'},
            {value: 5, name: 'data-d'},
            {
                value: 10,
                name: null,
                itemStyle:{opacity:0},
                tooltip:{show:false } 
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

};

Answer (score 2):

the way I did it was to put the echarts inside a wrapper div and then set height and overflow:

```
<div class="tracker-gauge">
  <div echarts [options]="chartOptions" (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)"></div>
</div>
```

And then in css:

```
.tracker-gauge {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 140px;

  div {
    height: 220px;
  }
}
```

Also, I used "gauge" chart instead of "pie" chart.

Answer (score 0):

The best

```
var start = 180*90/100;
var end = 180*10/100;
var discard = 180;

option = {
    series: [{
        name: 'half semi',
        type: 'pie',
        radius: ['50%', '70%'],
        center: ['50%', '100%'],
        startAngle: 180,
        clockwise: true,
        data: [{
                value: start,
                name: 'ok'
            },
            {
                value: end,
                name: 'bad'
            },
            {
                value: discard,
                name: 'discard'
            }
        ]
    }]
};
```

TEST: https://codesandbox.io/s/7ruys9?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm add summary for make half bottom of chart.

```js
const dataFromAPI = [
    { name: '25 - 35', value: 382 },
    { name: '35 - 45', value: 159 },
    { name: '>45', value: 83 },
];

const summary = dataFromAPI.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.value, 0);
const lastItem = dataFromAPI[dataFromAPI.length - 1];

if (lastItem.name !== '' && lastItem.value !== summary) {
    dataFromAPI.push({
        name: '',
        value: summary,
    });
}
```

Then I hidden half bottom chart.

```
    chartOption: EChartsOption = {
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'item',
        },
        legend: {
            top: '5%',
            left: 'center',
        },
        series: [
            {
                startAngle: 180,
                clockwise: true,
                type: 'pie',
                radius: ['50%', '60%'],
                center: ['50%', '100%'],
                avoidLabelOverlap: false,
                label: {
                    show: false,
                    position: 'center',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    padding: [0, 0, 50, 0],
                },
            },
        ],
    };
```